# Validating the new value of an editable table cell

Tags: java, javafx-8

I have a column inside of a TableView that only allows "Male" or "Female" values.

The cell within this column is modifiable and when the user inputs an incorrect string such as "Test" it creates an alert to notify them of the error.

The problem I am currently having is that after the alertbox is closed, it creates another another alertbox same as the previous one and this process just loops forever.

The code I have is:

```
    genderColumn.setCellFactory((TreeTableColumn<Person, String> param) -> new GenericEditableTreeTableCell<Person, String>(new TextFieldEditorBuilder()));
    genderColumn.setOnEditCommit((CellEditEvent<Person, String> t)->{

        if(t.getNewValue().toLowerCase().equals("male")){
            ((Person) t.getTreeTableView().getTreeItem(t.getTreeTablePosition().getRow()).getValue()).getGenderProperty().set("Male");; 
        } else if (t.getNewValue().toLowerCase().equals("female")){
            ((Person) t.getTreeTableView().getTreeItem(t.getTreeTablePosition().getRow()).getValue()).getGenderProperty().set("Female");;   
        } else {
            Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.ERROR);
            alert.setTitle("Invalid Gender");
            alert.setContentText("Please specify the gender as either Male or Female");
            alert.showAndWait();
            ((Person) t.getTreeTableView().getTreeItem(t.getTreeTablePosition().getRow()).getValue()).getGenderProperty().set(t.getOldValue());;    

        }

    });
```

Could you help me understand / fix why the Alert box is constantly generated?

Thank you.

Comment: My guess is when you call set on the table, it triggers the event to validate it, and this repeats forever since the value will never be correct.

Comment: @Kelvin tried to test that theory out, the code does not move past the "alert.showAndWait()" line so it just seems to be stuck on that, still unsure what the error is because these are the only lines of code I have for the column

Comment: Even when you close the Alert message?  Something must happen since I don't think it can stay on that line.

Comment: Yup even when I close the alert message. I've even tried getting the response from the buttons but that also does not return any values. I'm guessing its some interaction between the CellEdit event, table cell and the alert box that I'm missing out on, can't quite put my finger on it though

Comment: Why not just restrict what the user can do in the first place, e.g. using a combo box or check box?

Comment: @James_D Did not know that something like that existed! (Only just started learning JavaFX). Solved the method using your method thank you!